# Can any one explain this part?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    final String title;
    MyApp({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
    //... .
}
```

//I am a bigner and when I saw some videos , I saw this code.
//can any one explain it?

//I try to notice 3th line , but I don't find anything.

Comment: It's not really clear exactly what you're asking about, but you probably should read [The Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) first.

Comment: @mohamed do you want to know what that code does? Please be more explici

Comment: class MyApp is in MaterialApp body.excuse me for this not clear question.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyApp({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

This is a constructor for the MyApp class.

It has two optional (because os the '{}') params.

- key of the Type Key
- title (with will be automatically assigned to the atribute tittle)

the constructor will call the constructor of the supper class passing the key param that was received.

Hope I could help you.